# Empty page using sendIntent.putExtras(bundle), page not filled Android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android

I'm trying to send some stuff via mail or Bluetooth etc but not working very well.
I would like to see a text like this:
" Respiration Rate: 0 2.0 5.0 16.0 "...
To do that I've implemented a button and Resut.java stuff. When I try to click on the button and I choose e-mail, app open a mail and the text is only "Respiration Rate"

here click-button:

```
SRR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDoubleArray("TryThis",plot_array);
        sendIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Respiration Rate: " );
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));


    }
});
```

**result.java**:

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.rPPG;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseData;
import android.bluetooth.le.AdvertiseSettings;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.PointsGraphSeries;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class RespirationResult extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String Date;
    int RR;
    int il_risultato;
    double [] plot_array;
    int[] intArray;



    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    java.util.Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    private  String[] RRtoSent=new String[300];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_respiration_result);

        Date = df.format(today);
        TextView RRR = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.RRR);
        ImageButton SRR = (ImageButton)this.findViewById(R.id.SendRR);
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------risutato
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        double result = b.getDouble("key");
        plot_array=b.getDoubleArray("array");


        il_risultato=(int) Math.round(result);
        RRR.setText(String.valueOf(il_risultato)); //prima era RR, da mettere successivamente

        RRtoSent = new String[plot_array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < RRtoSent.length; i++) {
            RRtoSent[i] = String.valueOf(plot_array[i]);
        }


        //grafico

        GraphView graph;
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;       //an Object of the PointsGraphSeries for plotting scatter graphs
        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graphico);
        series= new LineGraphSeries<>(data());   //initializing/defining series to get the data from the method 'data()'
        graph.addSeries(series);                   //adding the series to the GraphView
        //series.setShape(PointsGraphSeries.Shape.POINT);

        // activate horizontal and vertical zooming and scrolling
        graph.getViewport().setScalableY(true);

        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.DKGRAY);

       // graph.setTitle("Respiration Rate/min");
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalAxisTitle("time(sec)");
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalAxisTitle("RR");

        // set manual X bounds
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setMinX(0.5);
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(100);

        SRR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putDoubleArray("TryThis",plot_array);
                sendIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Respiration Rate: " );
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));


            }
        });



    }


    public DataPoint[] data(){
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[plot_array.length];     //creating an object of type DataPoint[] of size 'n'
        for(int i=0;i<plot_array.length;i++){
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(i,plot_array[i]);
            values[i] = v;
        }
        return values;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent i = new Intent(RespirationResult.this, SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();

    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea about it? 
what's wrong or missing?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Android official site:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#EXTRA_TEXT)

> `public static final String EXTRA_TEXT`
>
> A constant CharSequence that is associated with the Intent, used with
>   ACTION_SEND to supply the literal data to be sent. Note that this may
>   be a styled CharSequence, so you must use Bundle.getCharSequence() to
>   retrieve it.

So you should convert your double array to `String` first before calling email app.

Step 1: Write a method which convert a double array to a string.

```
private String convertDoubleArrayToString(double[] array) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (double number: array) {
        sb.append(number).append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Step 2: Change your code to

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Respiration Rate: " + convertDoubleArrayToString(plot_array));
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because all you want to show must be part of the EXTRA_TEXT:

`sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "EVERYTHING YOU WANT TO PRINT HERE" );`

So you have to build a string with your data, then you create the extra with the complete string.